# Finite support of multiset and distribution functor

Tags: category-theory, coalgebras

It is unclear to me why in the distribution functor as well as in the multiset functor we require finite support. Below, I provided the definition from "Introduction to Coalgebra" by Bart Jacobs.

In several other sources, this is explained in a similar fashion, not at all. It is usually just stated that it is necessary for it to be finite, or to avoid infinte sums. As I do not have a background in math, I am assuming I must be missing something obvious.

Def: For a commutative monoid $M = (M,+,0)$ we define the multiset functor $M_M: Sets \to Sets$ on a set $X$ as
$$ M_M(X) = \{ \varphi: X \to M \mid supp(\varphi) \text{ is finite} \} $$
where $supp(\varphi) = \{ x \in X \mid \varphi(x) \neq 0\}$ is called the support of $\varphi$.

On a function $f: X \to Y$ one has $M_M(f): M_M(X) \to M_M(Y)$ via
$$M_M(f)(\varphi)(y) = \sum_{x \in f^{-1}(y)} \varphi(x) = \sum\{\varphi(x) \mid x \in supp(\varphi) \text{ with } f(x) = y\} $$

Comment: I think it's simply because the given monoid operation of $M$ is finitary: the sum of infinitely many elements is not defined (unless all but finitely many elements are $0$).

Comment: @Berci That was my guess as well. Any particular reason why one would not restrict to complete monoids?

Comment: @Alex Mainly because they’re exceedingly rare. You could study that but you wouldn’t capture the main examples.

Comment: Sometimes you have a topology to try to make sense of an infinite sum, but the sum itself is not a well-defined concept unless you ask properties (e.g. absolute convergence) that are not "algebraic" but entirely analytic.